# ng command is not working when using from a different folder

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I choose a different folder for a new angular project
When I type any form of ng command I am getting this error

```
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I tried the command

```
 npm install -g @angular/cli
```

by just opening cmd and also from the angular project folder from visual studio code.

This is what I am getting

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see 
https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer 
supported
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> 
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

> @angular/cli@12.0.5 postinstall 
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

+ @angular/cli@12.0.5
updated 1 package in 45.097s
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the answer by @Filip Huhta above.
If it doesn't work and you can't install angular due to some packages not being able to be overwritten, then try below:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli --force
```

Answer (score 0):

I have three different things you could try to solve your problem:

**1.** Try to confifgure your enviroment path for **Angular CLI**.

Go to: **Environment Tables** -> **System variables** -> **Path**:

> **Example path:** `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm`

**2.** You could also double check, if you have added your `angular-cli\bin`.

Example:

> `alias ng="path-to-your-global-node-modules/angular-cli/bin/ng"`
>
> ( Location of `ng` file in `npm` folder)

**3.** Try this command which could also solve this problem:

> `npm link @angular/cli`
>
> ( Sometimes you need to write `sudo npm link @angular/cli` to get this
> to work)

Comment: I added C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm to the system path variable... But still not working...

Comment: and how to know the path of    angular-cli\bin     ?